# Use cpu function in cuda

Tags: c++, cuda, parallel-processing

I would like to include a C++ function in a CUDA Kernel, but this function is written for CPU like this:

```
inline float random(int rangeMin,int rangeMax){
    return rand(rangeMin,rangeMax);
}
```

*Assume that the rand() function use either curand.h or Thrust cuda library.*

**I thought in use a Kernel function (with only one GPU thread) that would include this function as inline, so the cuda compiler would generate the binary for the GPU.**

**Is this possible? If so I would like to include another inlines functions written for the cpu in the CUDA kernel function.**

Something like this:

-- InlineCpuFunction.h and InlineCpuFunction.cpp

-- CudaKernel.cuh and CudaKernel.cu (this one include the above header and uses it's function in the CUDA kernel)

If you need some more explanation (as this may look confusing) please ask me.

Comment: Where will a GPU version of `rand()` come from?

Comment: Good question. Assume that the rand() function use either curand.h or Thrust cuda library if on GPU.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CUDA function call-able by either the device or host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726005/cuda-function-call-able-by-either-the-device-or-host)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tag the functions you want to use on both the device and the host with both the `__host__ __device__` decorators that way it's compiled for your cpu and gpu.